# explanation about the construction "doubt no that..."

Tags: vocabulary

> "... I **doubted *not* that** I might one day, by taking a voyage, seewith my own eyes the little fields, houses..."-- Charlotte Brontë

I am wondering as to the bold part construction, as I failed to find such a structure in any dictionary. Or would you please show me a rephrased or synonym word pr phrase rather than it?

Extracted from the book Vocabulary for the high school students

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched on the Internet for the phrase and it returned with Bible quotes and history books. It's an archaic use I think. *doubted not* simply means *did not doubt*.

One of such instances is here -

> *He ***doubted not*** the promised words, but believed without wavering, for -he knew well, that the same God who created heaven and earth, (John 1,) who...*

replacing it makes it simpler

> *He **did not doubt** the promised words, but believed without wavering, for -he knew well, that the same God who created heaven and earth, (John 1,) who...*